# Handle null in sql SELECTS with JOIN ON

Tags: mysql, select, null

Lets put I have these 3 tables:

main table:

```
  ID | OtherStuff1 | OtherStuff2 | IdProvince | IdTown 
-----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------
   1 |   Stuff1    |   Stuff2    |    NULL    |   1    
-----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------
   2 |   Stuff3    |   Stuff4    |      1     |  NULL
```

province table:

```
ID | ProvinceName 
---+--------------
 1 |  ProvName1
```

town table:

```
ID |   TownName   
---+--------------
 1 |   TwName1
```

Then I use one of these sql to print the information so it appears the name instead of the Id number.

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName 
    FROM main AS a 
    LEFT JOIN (province AS b, town AS c) 
    ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id) 
    WHERE a.IdProvince=1;
```

or

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName 
    FROM main AS a 
    LEFT JOIN (province AS b, town AS c) 
    ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id) 
    WHERE a.IdTown=1;
```

The problem comes that when it prints the result it comes like this:

```
  ID | OtherStuff1 | OtherStuff2 | ProvinceName | TownName 
-----+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------
   1 |   Stuff1    |   Stuff2    |    NULL      |  NULL
```

If one of the id's is put in NULL then even if there are other id's with numbers it puts NULL too. How do I avoid that without just delete the join of that column that is null likes this:

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, IdTown 
    FROM main AS a 
    LEFT JOIN (province AS b) 
    ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id) 
    WHERE a.IdProvince=1;
```

This would work if IdTown is NULL but I don't want this solution because there are much many rows and a lot other columns with Id's and it's impossible to go one by one checking which one is NULL and which one is not.

So I want a query like this but when there is a null it doesn't mess the other Id's putting all of them in NULL.

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName 
    FROM main AS a 
    LEFT JOIN (province AS b, town AS c) 
    ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id) 
    WHERE a.IdProvince=1;
```

Sorry the expected result for this query would be like this:

```
  ID | OtherStuff1 | OtherStuff2 | ProvinceName | TownName 
-----+-------------+-------------+--------------+--------
   2 |   Stuff1    |   Stuff2    |  ProvName1   |  NULL
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in the final result set ?

Comment: You tagged this question with both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server tags. Which are you using?

Comment: Please post expected result

Comment: I put the suggested tags but It's true I'm using mysql

Comment: If you don't know the answer please upvote this so others will see it and maybe help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. don't mix join notations  (a from clause should avoid the use of , if you're using the ANSI92 standards.  If using the ANSI 89 standards, then there should be no left join syntax)
2. I see no reason not to do two left joins back to main table (A) one for Province and one for Town...

.

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName 
FROM main AS a 
LEFT JOIN province AS b
  ON a.IdProvince = b.Id 
LEFT JOIN town as c 
 ON a.IdTown = c.Id
WHERE a.IdProvince=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the condition in your ON clause:

```
a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id
```

Here you are asking to LEFT JOIN 2 tables only when both conditions are met, which in your case they don't.

I would try to keep the 2 joins separate like so:

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, b.ProvinceName, c.TownName
FROM main AS a 
LEFT JOIN province AS b ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id)
LEFT JOIN town AS c ON (a.IdTown = c.Id) 
WHERE a.IdProvince = 1;
```